# android: how to override a listview's touch background

Tags: android

by default for an android listview, when you touch it, it has an orange color.
does anyone know how to override this?  there doesn't seem to be a method for it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a background for your item views based on a [State List Drawable](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).

Answer (score 0):

In the layout xml file, add the property

```
android:clickable="false"
```

to the listview.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem.

here is the api call

```
    postView.setSelector(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.transparent_selector));
```

so basically it's the "Selector" that you need to override.
and i just created a 10px by 10px transparent png. so now when you click on the items in the list view, nothing will show up. hope this helps everybody!